# Is there use for Windows built-in file/folder encryption if the PC has only one user?

Tags: encryption, decryption, windows-10

From what I gathered, Windows 10 built-in encryption decrypts file/folder when a specific user logs into Windows. In a PC that only has one user, I want to keep the files encrypted until the user is prompted with a password and only then the files are decrypted. If I understood correctly file encryption does not do this.

I want to know if Windows 10 built-in file encryption is useful to me in any way if my PC only has one user account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of EFS is that the unlock key is protected by your logon password. If you only have one user, then they can access the data. Additionally, if there's only one user account then you have no separation of privileges between you and someone else logged into your account.

If you want to have an encrypted drive that you need a password to open, consider something like [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).